# Granting read access to lambda service principal doesn't work as expected

Tags: aws-cdk

This may an a general AWS question, but still the way that CDK allows you to use this has an unexpected result in my opinion, and i'm not sure why.

in the code below i'm supposedly giving read permissions to the lambda service principal.
this doesn't work though and lambdas are unable to read from this bucket. 
the only way I could get them to work is to update their lambda policy, allowing them access to the bucket by arn.

why doesn't this work? and since it's allowed (the policy is set fine to the bucket)
what does this mean?

Thanks!

```
bucket = S3.Bucket(
    scope=self,
    id='MyBucket',
    versioned=True,
    block_public_access=S3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
    encryption=BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
    removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    lifecycle_rules=[bucket_lifecycle_rules],
)

lambda_service_principal = iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com')
bucket.grant_read(lambda_service_principal)
```

Comment: It is not the Lambda "service" that accesses the bucket. It is the IAM Role used by the Lambda function that accesses the bucket. That's why you need to either use a Bucket Policy that grants access to the IAM Role, or (better) add permissions to the IAM Role to access the bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you! if you want. to write it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the Lambda "service" that accesses the bucket. It is the IAM Role used by the Lambda function that accesses the bucket. That's why you need to either use a Bucket Policy that grants access to the IAM Role, or (better) add permissions to the IAM Role to access the bucket.

When the Lambda container is created, Lambda will 'assume' the IAM Role that is associated with the function. These credentials are then provided via the EC2 Instance Metadata Service in the same way that roles can be assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance.

The Lambda function will use these credentials to access services, so the requests will come "from the IAM Role" rather than from the Lambda service.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. what is the reason that is it better to add permissions to the IAM role of the lambda instead of the S3 resource policy?

Comment: Typically, an Amazon S3 bucket policy is used for "everyone", such as making the bucket public. Or, it can be used to grant access to an identity from a different AWS Account. An IAM Role is used to grant access to the app that uses the role, which in this case is the AWS Lambda function. If permissions are going to a user or an app, it's much clearer when those permissions are applied directly against the IAM User or IAM Role, rather than adding permissions to various Bucket Policies.